# On losing focus - input not auto-filling

Tags: jquery

So I have a multi-part form that is supposed to auto fill another input. I have used blur to recognize when the input has lost focus, but I cannot get it to auto fill the other input with the value of the input losing focus. What I have looks pretty simple and logical to me, simply is not working.

Any help is appreciated.

```
    company_name.blur(function(){
        $('#dba').val(company_name.val());
    });
```

**UPDATE**

It appears there is something more than what the eye is catching doing this. The easy answer below me should have been right, and I imagine my code is right and something else is doing the dirty work.

***I couldn't get the code highlighter to work nicely with my code so I have put it in a text file for you to view. 
Thanks again!***

http://www.codewithphp.com/form.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is `company_name` set to? The following works for me!

HTML

```
<div>Type something here:<input name="editMe" type="text" /></div>

<div>Populates here:<input name="target" type="text" /></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name=editMe]").blur(function() {
        $("input[name=target]").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MtUKa/1/)

Comment: company_name is set to var company_name = $('#company_name');

Although, I will try you input method and see if that works out better.

Comment: Update! That did not work for me. I will go ahead and post the whole code, because it appears to me it has to be something else doing the dirty work behind this not filling.

Comment: And an update. I just realized that I have this code inside of a click function.. so I'm going to try and check that out really quick.

Answer (score 0):

So, after checking out what was going on. My original code was changed to

```
    $('#company_name').blur(function(){
        $('#dba').val($(this).val());
    });
```

And MOVED outside of the click function.

The reason it was not feeling is because inside of the click function it didn't iterate BACK to the form to see if it was 'blurred'..

Better yet, I could have simply filled #dba val with company_name.val and lost the blur function.

Comment: Yup, I'll mark your answer as the answer - since you were jumped right on helping me out!